# Java: ServerSocket reading data from a client

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader

I am working on a simple programm for a university course. Here is the code that I have problems with:

```
//everything before this is unrelevant
String message = "";
BufferedReader br  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));    
     while((message = br.readLine()) != null) {
         System.out.println(message);
}
//everything after this is irrelevant
```

I also have a thread for accepting incoming connections and some other stuff that is irrelevant. The problem that I have is that I can read one message and after that nothing happens. I guess the readLine() method is the problem but I am not really sure how to solve it.
It even says in our assignment to use

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
```

to receive data.

Comment: Have you typed the message on the other side for the second time, so that this machine should display the message?

Comment: What do you mean? Let's say on my client "programm" I write hello, the server will print out hello. Anything else I write on the client side just won't get printed out on the server side.

Comment: Please show the complete message sending and receiving methods through socket streams. We need the relevant part of message sending and receiving only.

Comment: Try `telnet`ing to the server. You should be able to type in lines of text and see what happens.

Comment: Given we can't see your client code, I would more likely to believe it's your client which is not sending more than one line.

Comment: The thing is we only have to write the server side of the chat programm. We are already given a client programm.

Comment: @YoLo - No, if you want continuous output from server side, your client machine should also keep on passing values, which doesn't seem the case here.

Answer (score 0):

Your client is only sending one line. You therefore don't need the loop. You should read one line and then do whatever you're supposed to do with it.